# Marshall/UnMarshall Java objects : REST services in GWT (client side)

Tags: xml, rest, gwt, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have some REST services on my server (using RESTeasy).

I want to call my services on the client-side (GWT). I receive the xml response doing GET requests but i'm stuck in unmarshalling the response. I have the same problem with POST requests, i need to send serialized java objects and unmarshall the response.

I have heard of Overlay objects, piriti/RestyGWT (no support of xml), Errai (which seems to be a too heavy solution for my small project), parsing xml myself and reconstructing the object after, JAXB (is it recommended to use it on the client side ?), ...

What are the best pratices ?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer. Use Errai. It simplifies the de/marshalling process and is very easy to use. Even for smaller projects. The marshalling takes some time when using the devmode but you are already used to waiting at this part, arent you?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any mature project for jaxb in GWT. I guess it is because there is a good alternative to xml on client side (and on server side as well) - JSON. So there are not many "best practices" in this area. I can only suggest to look at gwtjaxb project

http://code.google.com/p/gwtjaxb/

but seems it wont solve all your problems.

If you cant change your server side I think you have to use something like piriti - maybe it will be untrivial but at least possible.